# TorchServe CORS Settings

Tags: pytorch

To enable CORS(cross origion resoure sharing) in TorchServe, I am using the following settings in the **config.properties**. Can you please have a look and let me know if I am using the right settings/syntax. My torchserve settings need to return header reponse as  **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"**

Note: not using a custom header

cors_allowed_origin=*

cors_allowed_methods=GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS

Reference: https://pytorch.org/serve/configuration.html#configure-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors

Comment: It seems ok. What is the problem?

Comment: Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.8.115:8080/predictions/densenet161. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.8.115:8080/predictions/densenet161. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: when I add "cors_allowed_origin=*" in the config.properties file, should the server send back "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " in the header response.